# Configuring an access list on a Cisco router

Tags: acl, cisco-ios

I'm trying to set up an acl on a cisco router. I want the router to allow connection to the http server, while blocking the connection to the ftp server. My setup:

**ip access-list extended blockade_ftp 

deny tcp any any eq ftp 

permit tcp any any eq www**

**int g0/1 

ip access-group blockade_ftp out**

Unfortunately, all traffic is blocked. Adding only permit tcp any any eq www doesn't work either because I can't connect to the http server. How should it be configured?

Comment: This question should be moved to https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/